# how do i register device with urban airship

Tags: java, android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am developing application that will receive push notification from urban airship . i manage to get push notification .
currently i have added this code in myapplication class

```
       AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions
            .loadDefaultOptions(Myapplication.this);
    UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
    PushManager.shared().setAlias("test");

    // Tags
    HashSet<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
    tags.add("tag1");
    tags.add("tag2");
    PushManager.shared().setTags(tags);
    PushManager.enablePush();
    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
    String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
    Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);
```

it always shows "You don't have any device tokens registered yet."
how i can register device with urban airship ? can any one help me out .

Comment: Urban Airship's SDK will automatically register your device tokens or APIDs for you. I recommend viewing their sample applications or their docs here: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html and here: http://www.urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
UA_LINFO(@"APNS device token: %@", deviceToken);

// Updates the device token and registers the token with UA. This won't occur until
// push is enabled if the outlined process is followed. This call is required.
[[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

}

Comment: OP is asking about Android, not iOS.